# How to invert the order of the y-axis labels in a levelplot?

Tags: r, lattice

I would like to change the labels of the y-axis ("Row") from decreasing (top to bottom) to increasing (top to bottom), to correctly match the plotted values. This should be done for any y-axis labels (automatically), not just be manually defining the values at the y-axis (in other words, how can I grab out the used labels on the y-axis, invert their order and then put them back in as labels? how would panel.levelplot() look like?). Also, this should be done without using additional packages.

```
library(lattice)
A <- outer(1:100, 1:100, FUN = function(x, y) (x+2*y)/300)
levelplot(t(A)[, nrow(A):1], xlab = "Column", ylab = "Row")
```

The idea is to visually match the structure of a matrix (diagonal going from top left to bottom right). Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set `ylim=c(100,1)` or, better yet, `ylim=c(100.5,0.5)`:

```
## Prepare figures with and without inverted y-axes, for easy comparison 
a <- levelplot(t(A)[, nrow(A):1], xlab = "Column", ylab = "Row")
b <- levelplot(t(A)[, nrow(A):1], xlab = "Column", ylab = "Row", 
          ylim=c(100.5, 0.5))

## Plot figs side-by-side to confirm that this works
library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(a, b, ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Josh, thanks. I didn't know that you can revert ylim, pretty nice. Apart from that, is there any automatic way to remove the tick without label (at row 100)? One can reduce the range a bit, but that's already suboptimal for nrow(A) small.

Comment: @MariusHofert - To control tick marks, use the `scales=` argument, documented in `?xyplot`. Here, you might want to add: `scales=list(x=list(at=20*(1:4)), y=list(at=20*(4:1)))`.

Comment: ... would be nice to automatically get the 'default scales' and then remove the last tick... (because the actual problem is a function which gets matrices of different sizes).

Comment: ... one can do that nicely with `x = list(at = pretty(1:nrow(A)))`... and so on.

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to construct a function like that, you might want to have a look at the [`xscale.components.*()` functions](http://latticeextra.r-forge.r-project.org/man/scale.components.html) supplied by the **latticeExtra** package, using them as templates for your own. To get the values used in the default scales (in order to modify them as you've described), use the `xscale.components.default()` and `yscale.components.default()` functions.

Comment: Thanks, Josh, very nice!